# Error creating version google cloud ai-platform. ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gcloud, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to deploy a model version in google cloud ai-platform.
I successfully create the model (called MyModel), but when I try to deploy a version of the model from the command line, it prompts the next error:

[*Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: problem in predictor - ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc' from 'six.moves' (unknown location) (Error code: 0)"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmPvy.png)

I actually created the model without troubles 2 weeks ago. I also was having the same problem with other models and I solved it with the next libraries in the setup:

- google-auth==1.18.0
- google-cloud-storage==1.31.2
- google-api-core==1.22.2

The way the model is created is to look at the model dist from a storage bucket (I uploaded it from the command line with no problems):

---

### Steps to create the model

1. Create targz file that will be uploaded to the cloud storage bucket next to the model

   - python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar
2. Upload tarball to gcloud storage

   - gsutil cp dist/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz gs://my-bucket
3. Create ai-platform model

   - gcloud beta ai-platform models create MyModel --regions my-region --enable-logging --enable-console-logging
4. Create version model (v1)

   - gcloud beta ai-platform versions create v1 --model MyModel --runtime-version 1.15 --python-version 3.7 --origin gs://my-bucket/model/ --package-uris gs://my-bucket/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz --prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor

---

### What have I tried

- Create the version with the last google libraries versions
- Create the version with the next libraries: google-auth==1.18.0, google-cloud-storage==1.31.2, google-api-core==1.22.2

I suppose it is something related with google libraries and their updates in the versions. I am open to all suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, the issue only presents itself when you try and deploy new versions? Also, can you easily reproduce the error, or does it happen randomly?

Comment: Yes, the error comes when I deploy new versions of the model. It always prompts the same import error.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the problem?  I'm seeing the same thing...

Comment: Unfortunately not.